# Could we prove the existence of equilateral triangle without using the notion of circle?

Tags: geometry

The first proposition of Euclid's Elements proves the existence of equilateral triangle by using the notion of circle. The axioms of Hilbert's geometry guarantee the existence of congruent segments, angles and triangles.

But could we prove the existence of an equilateral triangle without using the notion of circle?

Comment: of course, we can just use triangle inequality

Comment: More precision please Vasya?

Comment: we can check whether three congruent segments satisfy triangle inequality. If they do, a triangle can be constructed using such segments.

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand.

Comment: "if three real numbers are such that each is less than the sum of the others, then there exists a triangle with these numbers as its side lengths and with positive area". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality

Comment: I think that the proof of the existence of a triangle of which the three sides are congruent to three segments satisfying the triangle inequality uses the notion of circle.

Comment: not really, the proof in Wikipedia article based on Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: That proof does not actually construct the triangle. It only "proves" its existence.

Comment: @user49413 In other words, you are asking if an equilateral triangle can be constructed using only a ruler. Right?

Comment: @Aretino, No, I means to prove its existence based on axioms but without the definition of circle. It can be drawn doesn't prove formally its existence. And how it could be drawn has no importance in  formal proof if its existence could be proven. That is, we talk only in a formal system here.

Comment: @Vasya, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle seems prove only the area of an equilateral triangle by using Pythagorean theorem. It doesn't prove the existence of such an triangle.

Comment: @user49413: Look up the link to triangle inequality that I provided and check "Converse" section.

Comment: @user49413 It then depends on which axioms you can use. If you admit the axiom of segment transport and that of angle divisibility, an equilateral triangle can be easily proved to exist.

Comment: Why circle - you are basing the distance between points to prove the existence of a solution not related at all if there is circle or not.

Comment: @Aretino, we use Hilbert's system for example. There are many points in a plane. But the existence of a point having specific property needs to be proven. For example, the existence of a point common to two non parallel lines are guaranteed by axiom. The axiom of continuity guarantees the addition and multiplication. But division doesn't exist yet. So, the existence of segment of length multiple of another segment can be proven. But that of length of half of another needs still to be proven. The existence of an angle having some exact value other than $\pi$ needs also to be proven.

Comment: @Vasya, As we have only addition and multiplication, and division doesn't exist yet, we cannot use Pythagorean theorem to prove the existence of an equilateral triangle.